# Performance issue - getting data from Navision to PHP API

Tags: php, sql, api, csv, navision

I'm currently creating an API that has access to our Navision system. I'm pretty new to this, but I only added some functionality to an already existing system. The thing is:

**UPDATE 2:**

I think the version of Navision is irrelevant, since I'm querying the MSSQL database attached directly. Maybe the version of the MSSQL DB could be relevant:

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
Jun 12 2012 13:05:25 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

**UPDATE:**

I have already iterated over the CSV file and also the the search query is done every time a get a new email, since it cannot call the MSSQL server with an IN() statement with 70.000 emails in it.

I have also only opened the csv file for writing once instead of on every request.

**Completed:**

- I have a csv file with a lot of emails (done)
- This should be uploaded (done)
- The uploaded file should then be parsed for emails (done)
- The emails should then be matched up with the ones in Navision (done)

**Problem:**

- It takes a lot of time doing this
- Navision turns slow and there is a lot of people depending on that system on a daily basis.

**Info:**

- There are approx. 70.000 emails in the CSV file (and counting)
- We have approx. 1 million customers in Navision
- This script is supposed to run daily.
- Currently there is no joins in the SQL statement (this will come)

Do any of you have any suggestions on how to optimize the process?

Any help will be appreciated.

// Ulrik McArdle

Comment: Process the file after working hours, using Schedule Tasks.  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh879427(v=nav.71).aspx
We don't know the version of Navision that you have...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of how you've implemented the process it is impossible to talk specifics.  But, here are a couple of common pitfalls to avoid:

1) When writing a script to parse a large text CSV text file, do so line by line.  Do not try to load the file into memory - into a gargantuan array or some such.  This is hugely inefficient.  Rather, open the file and iterate over it line by line using something like a while loop and fgetcsv(), process that line, throw it away and load another.

2) Make the RDBMS - MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, whatever - handle the heavy work.  PHP is not the place to process the data.  Optimise the SQL statements, in other words.  I would assume that the "Navision turns slow" bit would best attended by attention to the SQL.

Comment: I actually started by doing it all at once, like you mentioned i pitfall 1). But I quickly change that to single line. I also opened and closed the file every time, again I changed that to only open it once. That all helped.

Comment: Opening and closing the file every time?  Every time you read a line?

Comment: Yes, I was doing that, but not anymore. I have a file with emails and for each email I connect to the MSSQL DB and retrieves the data from the customer with that email. Before I was opening and closing the output csv file on every email loop. But I changed that.